# Can't write to mysql database after authentication in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to write to the database after authenticating, but unable to.

Once I log in successfully, I redirect to index.php

```php
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
    $mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/database.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user
            WHERE id = {$_SESSION["user_id"]}";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/water.css@2/out/water.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <?php if (isset($user)): ?>
        <p>Hello <?= htmlspecialchars($user["name"]) ?></p>
        <form action="user-input.php" method="post" id="availDates">
            <label for="nickName">Nickname:</label>
            <input id="nickName" name="nickname" />
            
            <label for="startDate">Start Date:</label>
            <input type="date" id="startDate" name="startdate">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
       
        <p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p><a href="login.php">Log in</a> or <a href="signup.html">sign up</a></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

From here, I want to capture a name and a date and submit, but every time I submit, I look inside phpmyadmin and the table cells are blank.  I'm running this locally using xampp.  Here is the code where I am trying to capture input from the form:

```php
<?php

if (empty($_POST["nickname"])) {
    die("Name is required");
}

if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
   die("Name is required");
}

$mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/database.php";
$sql = "INSERT INTO user (nickname) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if ( ! $stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    die("SQL error: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("sss", $_POST["name"]);
                  
if ($stmt->execute()) {
  echo "successful";
} else {
    if ($mysqli->errno === 1062) {
        die("error");
    } else {
        die($mysqli->error . " " . $mysqli->errno);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You should do more error checking. Your `bind` will fail. You've specified 3 strings but provided only one value.

Comment: Why do you output `die("Name is required");` when the date is empty? Why do you immediately die() after a single validation issue? It would be much more user-friendly to give the user feedback on all their mistakes at once, and re-display the form so they can correct them.

Comment: Please bring your error handling into the 21st century. Add `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` before your `mysqli_connect()` (or `new mysqli()`) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. You'd have immediately got an error with your bind_param call(). Also that way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident.

Answer (score 0):

The form data has `name` attribute with values "nickname" and "startdate". I guess you should be using them correctly to construct the insert query with `$_POST["nickname"]` & `$_POST["startdate"]`

If you're still facing issue, then please post the full error log to debug.